# Enumerating Controls on a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach, enumeration

I have a form with about 30 controls on it, and when the user clicks a button, data from each control is saved to a file. But I need to go through every single control on the form (which I can do), but it needs to be in order, For example, I need to start right at the top left of the form and work my way down to the bottom right of the form.

Is this how a foreach loop would work? I.e.:

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
}
```

Or does it not go through them in order?

Comment: Do you need to enumerate the child-controls of your controls as well?

Comment: Ummmm, nah. Atm I only have buttons, labels, linklabels, textbox's and a few Checkbox's. But that'd be good if I ever add a Panel or split container in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would return the controls in the order they are added to the form, not in visual order.

If you have set up your `TabIndex` in the same order as you want to parse the controls you can use LINQ to sort them by `TabIndex`.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
{
}
```

Comment: Oh this is awesome. Yeah, I shouild've mentioned that, I am using Tab Index. :) Thanks!!!

Comment: But TabIndex may not be in same order as Visual appearance

Comment: @Kiran; Yeah it is. In Visual Studio, there's a Toobar Button that you click in the Design-View which enables you to simply click on a control to set its Tab-Index. :-)

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo can u provide me the .net 2.0 equivalent of above code? Linq doesnt work in mine.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to enumerate the child-controls of your controls as well?

If not, try

```
foreach(Control control in this.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(o => o.Location.Y).ThenBy(o => o.Location.X)
{
    ...
}
```

This will enumerate the controls, beginning in the upper-left and moving right, then down.

Comment: According to specification! Will work fine if all controls in one row are positioned exactly at the same `Y`. If you put a label and a textbox nicely aligned in a row they don't have the same `Y`. That might or might not be a problem depending if the controls are of mixed types or not.

Comment: Thanks heaps @BlueRaja - I didn't know you could do that. I thought it would be alot more gritty

Comment: @Albin: You could also sort by the center of the controls, rather than upper-left, by replacing `o.Location.Y` with `o.Location.Y + o.Height/2` (and `o.Location.X` with `o.Location.X + o.Width/2`).  Or, you could sort by distance to the upper-left using simply `.OrderBy(o => o.Location.Y*o.Location.Y + o.Location.X*o.Location.X)`.  Both of these have advantages and disadvantages.  Because controls do not always align nicely to a grid, there is no way to enumerate them perfectly in "reading-order" - OP will need to better define how he wants them ordered if none of these suggestions will do.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflugho can u provide me the .net 2.0 equivalent of above code? Linq doesnt work in mine.