# C# edit property of panel using run-time generated button

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I'm a complete noob in C# programming. This is my problem: I have a form with a panel that is generated upon clicking button 1, the panel also containes a button (btnColor1) to change the backcolor of the panel. I would like to refer to the panel's backcolor in btnColor1, but I get the error "The name 'btnColor1' does not exist in the current context". How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TEST_APP_1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Panel myPanel1 = new Panel();
        myPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 50);
        myPanel1.Name = "Panel 1";
        myPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        myPanel1.BackColor = Color.Red;

        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(10, 50);
        textBox1.Text = "empty field";
        textBox1.Size = new Size(150, 30);

        Button btnColor1 = new Button();
        btnColor1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        btnColor1.Text = "GOLD";
        btnColor1.Size = new Size(100, 30);
        btnColor1.Click += myButton1_Click;

        myPanel1.Controls.Add(textBox1);
        myPanel1.Controls.Add(btnColor1);

        Controls.Add(myPanel1);
    }

    private void myButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        btnColor1.BackColor = Color.Gold;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you need new buttons, new panel to be created for every button click? If not, you can simply store the `btnColor1` as a field in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the parent property of the button to access the panel and the form:

```
private void myButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button but = (sender as Button);
        but.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        // this changes the color of the panel
        but.Parent.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        // this changes the color of the form containing the panel
        if (but.Parent.Parent != null)
        {
            but.Parent.Parent.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

btnColor1 is declared in the scope of the button1_Click method so does not exist as a variable to reference in your event handler. Change the event handler to this:

```
private void myButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Gold;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kell, I tried the code, but I got a break. Removed the `throw new NotImplementedException();`, this works, but the code makes my button gold, not the background of the panel. My aim is not only change color of the container, but alter a lot of other properties of other controls, just by clicking one (run-time generated) button.

Comment: @Dr.Mojo, if you need that, then that's what you have to do. Add code for each property you want to modify into event handler, make all controls you want to be modifiable accessible somehow. It is possible to [enumerate controls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5265903/1997232) of current form and you can use `Tag` property to hold identification or some other sort of data. In this case you don't need to un-localize (making not local) all controls (such as `btnColor1`).

Comment: Yeah, what Sinatr said :)